# Why does QGIS spontaneously corrupt shapefile data?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, ubuntu, corrupt

I'm using QGIS 2.14 (Mac), but I have had the same problem with 2.8 (Ubuntu). When I am editing a shapefile, QGIS seems to spontaneously corrupt the data in unpredictable and catastrophic ways that include:

- Duplication of features
- Deletion of features
- Scrambling of attribute data

Most recently, this occurred while using the Table Manager plugin to rename a column of the attribute table. Upon saving the change, one of the columns of the attribute table (not the one being renamed) was suddenly scrambled such that features were unpredictably reclassified, completely corrupting the file and forcing me to reload a backup version.

The problem seems to be associated with saving, though I usually don't discover the corruption until some time after it occurred, so I can't say for sure what the circumstances were in most cases, the exception being the case described above.

I realize this might be the same problem described here

[QGIS corrupting shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159183/qgis-corrupting-shapefiles)

If so, it is evidently still a problem in 2.14, and there was never a satisfactory answer provided. If not, does anyone have a clue as to what is going on? This makes QGIS completely unusable.

-------------- EDIT ---------------

I was able to replicate the result by reloading a backup version and repeating the renaming and saving that precipitated the corruption the first time. The problem seems to be specifically with the Table Manager plugin, similar to what was reported here: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13316

Apparently it remains unresolved, so I guess one should stay away from Table Manager for the time being.

Comment: Since you don't seem to be adding anything new to the discussion in the other question I think this is a duplicate. See what the bug tracker shows and if you think it doesn't seem to be there log a new bug. Failing that break out a debugger and find out what the issue is.